# Restricted access on certain files in Open Atrium

Tags: files, distributions

I have a situation where I have individuals that belong to a certain group and they want to have a sub-folder in the documents subspace that is restricted to only a few members of that space.

In my research I have come across a private file system that you can configure/set up, but that solution is not ideal as we still want to keep all the documents for that space in one central location.

Is it possible to break permissions down to level of special access on individual folders/files?

Information:

1. Using latest version of Open Atrium.
2. Have no other modules installed.
3. Current users are used to working with SharePoint as their CMS.

I apologize if I am missing something obvious or have holes in my basic understanding of Drupal, as I have been forced to dive in head first with out testing the waters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could create 2 files sections. The first one, accessible to everyone. Then another one, in a subspace, that would be private (check settings upon creation).

Maybe you could display then the whole structure using only one "files and folder" widget if this is what you need

Comment: sorry I have not gotten back to this, things got crazy and I dont really check the email I created for stack.  I did something very similar to what you suggested.  Made a new space, added links to the new space on the desired page and provided a quick link back to the original site. It was not an ideal solution, but got the job done.  Since you said what I basically I did, I am marking your solution as correct for future readers.